# A function to swap two variables

Tags: c, function, pointers, swap

I am a newbie and learning the pointer now. I encountered this problem:

function 1:

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int *p;
    *p=*x;*x=*y;*y=*p;
}
```

function 2:

```
void swap(int *x, int *y){
    *x=*x+*y;*y=*x-*y;*x=*x-*y;
}
```

I know the function 2 can work well to swap two variables but function 1 cannot. Why? Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: function 2 is serious obfuscation.

Comment: @simon-No, I don't agree. One must be ready to perform these things,suppose if someone is asked to swap two numbers without using any temp variable! What say you?

Comment: @shekharsuman, I completely agree. It might be an academic example but still a good "computer person" should know these things. Problem with this solution is the risk of causing an overflow.

Comment: @shekharsuman, a) It's not realistic, b) I merely have stated that the intention of the second function is much less transparent. Do you not agree?

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because you've received multiple answers based on the initial content. Your edit changes the entire meaning of the question, and therefore it invalidates all of the answers you've received. If you now have a totally different question, ask it in a new post. Please **do not** edit it again to change the variable names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In function1, you are using a pointer `p` that isn't pointing to a valid address. You don't need a pointer here:

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int p;
    p=*x;*x=*y;*y=p;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, because, you've passed `a` and `b`, and using `x` and `y`, (which, in case, are not defined here).

In a serious note, for a pointer defined as `int *p;` and no memory allocated, using

```
    *p=*x;
```

i.e., de-referencing the pointer invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As mentioned rightly in [Yu Hao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30402113/3137699), you can make use a simple `int` variable, no need for a pointer.